# How to use AVAudioPlayer to play sound effects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, avaudioplayer

Whenever I play my `AVAudio` clip, the clip plays, and then it crashes a moment later.  I can't figure out why. When it crashes, it doesn't give me anything in the log. Here is my code. I've also imported `AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h` and `AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h`

```
-(void)soundEffect {
    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *filePath = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"BlastWAV" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSError *error = nil;

    avSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:fileData error:&error];
    [avSound prepareToPlay];

    [avSound play];
}
```

Comment: @mohacs thanks for the edits.  Any suggestions on how to solve the issue at hand?

Comment: Where does it crash, what does it say, and if you use exception breakpoints what does it say? We need those kinds of details. Is either filePath or fileData nil? And since this is posted with a cocos2d tag, why are you simply not using SimpleAudioEngine (assuming cocos2d 2.x)?

Comment: @AllenS you're the man!  That worked perfectly.  I'm new to ObjC and Cocos. Had no idea what SimpleAudioEngine was, but I looked it up and it was just an easy solution.  Thank you!  (If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll make sure to select it as correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

Since you are using cocos2d you can use the SimpleAudioEngine if you are using v2.x or OALSimpleAudio if you are using v3.x like so:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"sound.caf"];
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"sound.caf"];
```

and when you are done with it at the end of the scene:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] unloadEffect:@"sound.caf"];
```

For v3 the equivalent is:

```
[[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] preloadEffect:@"sound.caf"];
[[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] playEffect:@"sound.caf" loop:NO];
[[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance] unloadAllEffects];
```